# How to download images/files by AWS S3 secured URLs on mobile app OR WEB?

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, base64, android-download-manager

Right Now,
The S3 URLs are private.(To avoid direct access from any un-authorised user)So we are not able to access S3 urls directly. To overcome this issue we are sending base64 string of attachment in API response.On web there is no such difficulties for me to handle this scene. But for mobile APP i am facing issue. So following are the some questions related to it.

1.Is it good idea to use base64 string on mobile APP? (Because payload will go in MB`s)
2. I also come to know about pre-signed urls. Are they safe? Because here we are providing a temporary url(Last for some time).

For react native mobile apps to download files we need http/https file url. Is there any other way to handle this issue?
Is there any other way to tackle this situation.

Comment: Presigned URLs are indeed what you should be going for. Define what you mean by "safe". Yes, a presigned URL allows anyone who has that URL to download the file for a certain amount of time that you control. What about this may be "unsafe"? They'll get the image one way or the other; they have to, otherwise it's pretty pointless.

Comment: Hello Deceze, Thanks for reply. Yes my concern about the safe/unsafe is anyone has the pre-signed url can access or download the file. The data is very much confidential so i dont think its a good way to deal with it.

Comment: If you don't trust the client, then you shouldn't send them the confidential image in the first place. There's little difference whether the untrustworthy client saves the image and gives it to someone else, or gives the signed URL to someone else to download the image from there.